# 'Can't find module fs' when running casperjs on js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to run CasperJS on a javascript file that I have, and when I run

```
> casperjs index.js
```

it says

```
'CasperError: Cant find module fs'.
```

The first line of index.js is

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

I have node, casperjs, and phantomjs installed, why can't it find fs? If I am correct, fs is Node's file system?

UPDATE: I added nodejs to my $PATH, but still no luck.

Comment: Fyi, casperjs uses the fs module within phantomjs, not the node fs module.

Answer (score 13):

Did you install the PhantomJS/CasperJS modules as well as the node fs module in your project? They don't seem to mix very well.

I ran into an issue where installed all of these modules and I was getting the same error message you mentioned above.

> CasperError: Can't find module fs

Once I uninstalled the node 'fs' module, everything worked fine.

```
npm uninstall fs
```

Comment: Your advice works, but I have some casperjs scripts in my project and some other npm modules. The casper scripts live in the project for convenience so I don't have them separated. Just having the fs module in the node_modules causes this behavior even if I'm not using it. Any time I run js files within a path that has a `node_modules` folder, I get this error. Any ideas on how to stop phantomjs/ casperjs from getting the npm fs module?

Answer (score 0):

Are casperjs and phantomjs installed globally ?

Answer (score 0):

CasperJS is depending on PhantomJS, which have a built-in fs module. In Casper script, you are only able to use the phantomjs built-in `fs` module. See http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/

To solve the problem you describe, you will need to make sure there is no `fs`module defined in the package.json, or run `npm uninstall fs`