# unable to run basic casperjs code - CasperError: Cant find module fs

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

i tried running the sample code provided in the casperjs homepage, but i got this error .

I'm trying it on mac,

```
I'm using version for casperjs  = 1.1.3
phatomjs version  =  2.1.1
```

whenever i try tu run it wiht this command it spits error

casperjs sample.js

output >

```
CasperError: Cant find module fs
casperjs sample.js
CasperError: Can't find module fs

  phantomjs://code/bootstrap.js:297 in patchedRequire
  phantomjs://platform/colorizer.js:35
CasperError: Can't find module fs

  phantomjs://code/bootstrap.js:297 in patchedRequire
  phantomjs://platform/casper.js:36
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'require('casper').create()')

  phantomjs://code/sample.js:1 in global code
  :0 in injectJs
  phantomjs://code/bootstrap.js:435
```

Heres my code.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

fyi:  I installed casper and phantom via brew in the past.

I'm willing to use  node module route,  or by installing the master branch from github or any other route to get it working. Kindly advise.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "automationtools",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: - no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/casperjs main.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "casperjs": "^1.1.3",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.7"
  }
}
```

I'm using all these node packages on local. I dont know if they're picked up from here or from global. Please suggest how do I check that ?

Im running it via  `$ npm start`  which is a shortcut thats there in the package file.

Please feel free to ask me any questions, how I can narrow down this question.

Question: It says that can't find fs, but i read somewhere that fs is now part of node itself.

```
○ node --version
v4.5.0
```

Comment: Having the same pain...see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641513/cant-find-module-fs-when-running-casperjs-on-js-file

Comment: yeah, no help from github issue or google groups.   giving up on casperjs for now..   I'm trying out nightmare js,  https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare   its looks nice!

Comment: @PaulRedmond  just fire a docker instance on your make, it works great for casperjs and phantomjs

Comment: this issue just paralyzed me from adding casper.js scripts to any of my node projects directly ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42372220/unable-to-run-basic-casperjs-code-caspererror-cant-find-module-fs `npm uninstall fs` worked for me as well